# How I can get hash from random tuple or array in Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I have a function(random_typle) parametr as a random tuple, so how can I get a hash from all fields of a tuple?
Can I use something like tuple:bsize() or should iterate all fields and calc hash?

Answer (score 0):

Tarantool has built-in `digest` module with collection of hash functions. Below I put an example of a function to calculate crc32 hash of a tuple.

```lua
local digest = require('digest')
local function calc_hash(tuple)
    local crc32 = digest.crc32.new()
    for _, v in ipairs(tuple) do
        crc32:update(tostring(v))
    end
    return crc32:result()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `vshard.router.bucket_id_mpcrc32(key)` [source code](https://github.com/tarantool/vshard/blob/b3c27b32637863e9a03503e641bb7c8c69779a00/vshard/router/init.lua#L1634).
This function calculates hash out of lua `key` object inside.
I have a case where I need `bucket_id` and `hash`.
So I have to clone this method and return bucket and hash from it.